# How can I change a folder's icon by using a script?

Tags: scripts, directory, customization

I have in my Profile folder "Home" some specials folders as "Wallpapers", "TXT", etc. and I use, for those personalized icons. The problem is that, any time I reinstall Ubuntu, I have to assign again the icon to that particular folder, and with the years and the installs, the number of folders are increasing.

So I need a automatic way to assign those custom icons to those special folders. Is there a way to do that?

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar was discussed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1383270). I guess, according to the thread, you could use `gvfs-set-attribute` to change the icons and using a [for loop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) you could make your script shorter by iterating over your standard folder names and icon locations.